# Taylors Theorem C

Tags: c, taylor-series

I've got simple code for Taylor's Theorem for `cosh()` function.

I'm trying to catch a mistake - the result is sometimes close the real answer.

How to do it correctly?

When my **start** is 0, **end** is 5, and **subdivides** is 5 it gave good results, but when I put 5 as start and 10 as end, the result is farther away from the expected value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int poww( float number, int a )
{
    float result = 1.0;
    int i;
    if( a != 0 );
    {
        for( i = 0; i < a; i++ ) {
            result = result * number;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int factorial(int n)
{
    switch (n) {
    case 0:
        return 1;
        break;
    default:
        return n * factorial(n-1);
    }
}

void main()
{
    puts("Enter start: ");
    float start;
    scanf("%f", &start);

    puts("\nEnter end: ");
    float end;
    scanf("%f", &end);

    puts("\nSubintervals:");
    int subinterval;
    scanf("%d", &subinterval);

    float h = (end - start) / (float)subinterval;
    printf("h is : %3.2f \n", h);

    double x, result, temp;
    int n;

    for( x = start; x <= end; x += h) {
        result = 0;
        for(n = 0 ;  ; n++) {
            temp = poww(x, 2 * n) / (factorial( 2 * n ) * 1.0);
            if(temp < 0.00001) {
                break;
            } else {
                result = result + temp;
                printf("X = %f temp = %f, result = %f\n", x, temp, result);
            }
        }
        printf("X = %f, result = %3.2f, cosH = %3.2f\n\n", x, result, cosh(x) );
    }
    puts("Press any key...");
    getchar();
}
```

PROBLEM SOLVE:

function returns an integer instead of double, also I changed every float to double.

Comment: Why are you printing the result of exp?

Comment: what's the expected result and the actual one?

Comment: "the result is sometimes close the real answer" – well isn't that something you want? do you want the result to be far from the actual answer?

Comment: Of course, there should be **cosh** instead of **exp**, but it's still wrong. Expected = cosH, actual = result

Comment: WTF? Do I really have to rephrase my question?

Comment: @MikeHousky Done. Still doesn't work.
@KarolyHorvath I would like that the **result** variable, after all iterations, was very close to the real result of `cosh()` function. So my actual value is stored in `result`. Check out last printf in first for loop.

Comment: What happens if you make `poww` and `factorial` work with `double`s instead of `float`s?

Comment: Sorry about earlier remark.  It's true, but not the problem here.  I see a poww() function that returns an int instead of a double as more than problematical.

Comment: Do you mean Taylor Series?

Comment: @KurdTt-: numbers please... expected, actual.

Comment: @AustinMullins Of course! That was that. I forgot about return type. Thank you so much.

Comment: @iharob Yes, indeed. My fault.

Comment: Also, the factorial gets WAY outside the range of an int in this problem.  Change the return type there to a double.  Formulating an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all `float` types to `double` and use `double` as the return type for the `factorial()` and `poww()` functions, too.  It's the last two that are most important in this case.

Also, the return type on `main()` should be `int`, not `void`.

*[I just finished removing the dead if statement in poww(), and noticed that the function only "speeds up" a pow() computation.  If you're worried about performance, worry about computing a factorial and a power on every term, rather than multiplying the previous term by x^2 and dividing by (2*n)*(2*n-1).]*

I get good results between 4 and 10 on this minor fix of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double poww( float number, int a )
{
    float result = 1.0;
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < a; i++ )
    {
        result = result * number;
    }
    return result;
}

double factorial(int n)
{
     switch (n)
      {
            case 0: return 1;
                    break;
            default: return n * factorial(n-1);
      }
}

int main(){

    puts("Enter start: ");
    float start;
    scanf("%f", &start);

    puts("\nEnter end: ");
    float end;
    scanf("%f", &end);

    puts("\nSubintervals:");
    int subinterval;
    scanf("%d", &subinterval);

    float h = (end - start) / (float)subinterval;
    printf("h is : %3.2f \n", h);

    double x, result, temp;
    int n;

    for( x = start; x <= end; x += h){
        result = 0;
        for(n = 0 ;  ; n++){
            temp = poww(x, 2 * n) / (factorial( 2 * n ) * 1.0);
            if(temp < 0.00001){
                break; }
            else{
                result = result + temp;
                printf("X = %f temp = %f, result = %f\n", x, temp, result);
            }
        }
                printf("X = %f, result = %3.2f, cosH = %3.2f\n\n", x, result, cosh(x) );
    }

    puts("Press any key...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest `float result = 1.0;` --> `double result = 1.0;`

Comment: `if( a != 0 );` does not do anything - notice the final `;`.  Anyways, `if( a != 0 );` is not needed.